Show the backface using -1 times identity matrix in CSS
I would like to apply the homography  to a square of side length 200px, where k ranges from 0 to 0.02.
According to this demo, for a square of side length 2, when k=1, the left edge will go to infinity, and when k>1, the "backface" will emerge from the right side.
In my case, the square is of side length 200px. When k=1, the left edge will go to infinity, and when k>0.01, the "backface" will emerge from the right side.
Initial attempt:


#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: squareMotion 2s alternate linear infinite;
  background: rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
}

@keyframes squareMotion {
  from {
    transform: matrix3d(
      1,0,0,0,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      0,0,0,1
    );
  }
  to {
    transform: matrix3d(
      1,0,0,0.02,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      0,0,0,1
    );
  }
}
<div id="div1">
</div>



but the backface (when k>0.01) doesn't show up.
I can see a self-intersecting quadrilateral in Firefox's element inspector. The expected "backface" should be on the right on the exterior of it.

Then I put an identical <div> inside it, which serves as "backface".


#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: squareMotion 2s alternate linear infinite;
  background: rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
}

#div2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
  transform: matrix3d(
    -1,0,0,0,
    0,-1,0,0,
    0,0,-1,0,
    0,0,0,-1
  );
  background: rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
}


@keyframes squareMotion {
  from {
    transform: matrix3d(
      1,0,0,0,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      0,0,0,1
    );
  }
  to {
    transform: matrix3d(
      1,0,0,0.02,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      0,0,0,1
    );
  }
}
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>



then the gray "backface" shows up on the right, as expected.

I think, -1 times identity matrix gives the same homography as the identity matrix.
In the above I wonder why -1 times identity matrix could be used to show the "backface".
matrix3d(
  -1,0,0,0,
  0,-1,0,0,
  0,0,-1,0,
  0,0,0,-1
);

(This "backface" concept seems to be different from the common "backface" in CSS backface-visibility, but I don't know if there is a suitable word for it. But if you compute the homography carefully, you will find that the interior of the square is mapped to precisely the gray area under the homography.)
